# Failed to open /dev/mem, try checking permissions

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run this program and save the output to a text file:

```
//Include ArduPi library
#include "eHealth.h"

//Needed for eHealth
eHealthClass eHealth;

// The loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {

  float ECG = eHealth.getECG();

  printf("ECG value :  %f V\n",ECG);
  delay(1000);
}

int main (){
   //setup();
   while(1){
      loop();
   }
   return (0);
}
```

It runs for a couple of seconds and then I get the following error:

```
Failed to open /dev/mem, try checking permissions.
Failed map the physical GPIO registers into the virtual memory space
Failed to open /dev/mem, try checking permissions.
Failed to map the physical BSCO (I2C) registers into the virtual memory space
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running as root ?

Comment: yes i do. sudo ./myprogram, and I also did sudo ./myprogram > output.txt

Comment: And exactly what are the permissions on /dev/mem etc?

Comment: if found it and it has the following rights: crw-r----T 1